# Controlling The Massive Spacing Between TH Elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've checked about 50 links in the past 20 minutes and tried every combination of stuff I can think of but there is still this massive automatic gap between my `th` elements, as seen in the picture below.

The test column will eventually be removed so that item has a colspan of 2, but in the mean time I cannot figure out how to remove this gap.

As you can see, `item` and `test` are very close, which is what I want. The rest are miles apart, and it's getting extremely annoying that I cannot solve this.

**Picture:** http://i.imgur.com/Herr27e.png

**Markup & CSS:
Both generated from HAML and SCSS respectively.**

```
<div class="ticker">
      <h2>NEW LISTINGS</h2>
      <div class="ticker-body">
        <table id="new-listings">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Item</th>
              <th>test</th>
              <th>Seller</th>
              <th>Seller Wants</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="item-image">
                <div class="item-image-container">
                  <a href="#"></a>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>Item Name</td>
              <td>tsujp</td>
              <td>Something Else Here</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="item-image">
                <div class="item-image-container">
                  <a href="#"></a>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>Item Name</td>
              <td>tsujpdsds</td>
              <td>Something Else  Here</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
.ticker
{
    .ticker-body
    {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid $type25Border;

        @include transition( border 0.2s ease-in-out );

        &:hover
        {
            border: 1px solid $greenText;
        }
    }


}

    table#new-listings
    {
    width: 645px;
    color: $whiteText;

    thead
    {
        font-family: "opensans-SB";
        font-size: 14px;

        th
        {
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
        }
    }

    th, td
    {
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    }

    tbody
    {
        tr
        {
            font-family: "opensans-R";
            font-size: 12px;
            //border-top: 1px solid $type35Border;

            &:nth-child(odd)    { background-color: $type60Background; }
            &:nth-child(even)   { background-color: $type70Background; }

            .item-image
            {
                width: 45px;
                height: 32px;

                .item-image-container
                {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    background-size: contain;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-position: center;
                    background-image: url( "src/hornmask.png" );
                    border: 1px solid $type35Border;
                    box-shadow: $softShadow;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question completely, but you have a fixed width on your table, so I'm not sure how it's supposed to shrink. Are you trying to keep the fixed size table and just compress the columns towards the left, or...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, I am trying to compress the columns to the left for the width of the stuff they contain.

Comment: Remove this fixed width on table or use real content if this width is expexcted (there won't be 3 words max in each cell of last column). Without `table-layout: fixed`, the default layout algorithm for tables is "adapt to the content" so do put real content in your table ;) (edit: and be sure to test on Safari 6. This browser is... different /Forrest Gump)

Comment: Ohh it's a default algorithm for spacing. I thought it was some roll on effect with one of my CSS rules. I am using Safari 6 right now haha :) - Macbook Pro. Thanks for that dude, I will populate it with actual data and just adjust the size from there.